# Asking about the running time of a program

Tags: ocaml, coq

I write a parser program (written in OCaml) that taking an input is a xsd and then generate it to Coq file. But it took a lot of time (~: 0m.0152s) to generate in the terminal. I would like to know some suggestions to be able to make a praser run faster? for example what is the reason that make a program slow? This is a first times I face with this running time problem. So I am very appreciate for any suggestion/experiences about it?

Thank you very much

EDIT:
I can try to explain by the main file:

```
open Libxml;; (*it is the library for xml file*)
open Error;; (* it is for the error message*)

let main () =     
  let xml = parse_xml stdin in
  let xsds = Xsd_of_xml.xsd_of_xml xml in (* It is a parsing from xml to xsds *)
  let b = Buffer.create 10000 in

  Coq_of_xsd.genr_coq b xsds; (* It is a parsing from xsds to Coq type *)
  Buffer.output_buffer stdout b;;

let _ = run main;;
```

I write an `Makefile.xsd2coq` like this:

```
MAIN := xsd2coq

FILES := util error libxml xsd scc xsd_of_xml coqxsd_matrix coqxsd_print coq_of_xsd

FRAGILE_FILES := xsd coqxsd_matrix coqxsd_print coq_of_xsd

LIBS := xml-light/xml-light

INCLUDES := -I xml-light

coq_of_xsd.cmo coq_of_xsd.cmx libxml.cmo libxml.cmx: WARNINGS = -warn-error Aezk

include Makefile.ocaml
```

In a main: `Makefile`

```
xsd2coq: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.xsd2coq depend
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.xsd2coq
```

Comment: Explain how do you measure the time and maybe we can help you there.
If that is 0.0152s from the beginning (ie time), then there is lot of stuff happening (setting up the runtime and initializing the vm) and your running code may be despicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was testing my parser-combinators I was using [that](http://www.ocamlpro.com/blog/2012/08/08/profile-native-code.html). I have seen that 70% of time is spend to blocks allocation. Maybe profiler output will help you to find similar problem.